# Fields from another table in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel-nova

Laravel Nova 3.8. How can I create a new fields in a resource that will be saved to another table when the resource is updated? Without creating a second resource. Is it possible? Didn't find this in the documentation

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare fields in resource and after that use YourModelObserver `saving` method to create some data in another table from `request`